# Let $X$ be a normal standard random variable and $a>0$ compute the characteristic function of $ Y:= X 1_{|X|\leq a}-X 1_{|X|>a}$

Tags: probability-theory, characteristic-functions

> Let $X$ be a normal standard random variable and $a>0$ compute the characteristic function of
> $$ Y:= X 1_{|X|\leq a}-X 1_{|X|>a}$$

For definition
$$\varphi_Y (t)=E[e^{itY}]= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{it(X 1_{|x|\leq a}-X 1_{|x|>a})}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}dx$$
$$\Rightarrow \varphi_Y (t)=\int_{-a}^{a} e^{itx}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}dx+\int_{-\infty}^{-a} e^{-itx}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}dx+\int_{a}^{\infty}e^{-itx}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}dx$$

I try to compare these expresion with
$$\varphi_X(t)=\int_{-a}^{a} e^{itx}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}dx+\int_{-\infty}^{-a} e^{itx}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}dx+\int_{a}^{\infty}e^{itx}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}dx$$
but i not sure to these is the right way any hint or help i will be very grateful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on the right track. Just notice that if we make the substitution $x\mapsto -x$ in the second and third integrals, we have

\begin{align}
\varphi_Y(t)&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-a}^{a} e^{itx-\frac{x^2}{2}}dx+ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{a}^{\infty} e^{itx-\frac{x^2}{2}}dx+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{-a}e^{itx-\frac{x^2}{2}}dx\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{itx-\frac{x^2}{2}}dx\\
&=e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}}.
\end{align}

So, in fact, we have that $Y$ has the same distribution as $X$, since we know that this is the characteristic function of a standard normal random variable.

Can you see why we do not have that $\varphi_Y(t)=\varphi_{X1_{|X|\leq a}}(t)\varphi_{X1_{|X|>a}}(-t)$?